# Mac Catalyst error: Cannot override 'paymentQueue' which has been marked unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, macos, in-app-purchase, mac-catalyst

I have an iOS app in Swift that implements the `paymentQueue(_:shouldAddStorePayment:for:)` method in `SKPaymentTransactionObserver`. When I am porting this app to Mac using Mac Catalyst, however, whenever I try to compile and run it on Mac it gives me this compile error which says "Cannot override 'paymentQueue' which has been marked unavailable".

I tried adding `#if os(iOS) ... #endif` and `@available(iOS 11, *)` statements around the `paymentQueue` method but it still gives me this error.

Here is the error-ridden code currently:

```
#if os(iOS)
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment, for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
    return true
}
#endif
```

Anyone else encountering this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent code from being compiled into a Mac Catalyst build with the `!targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)` condition:

```
#if !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue,
                  shouldAddStorePayment payment: SKPayment,
                  for product: SKProduct) -> Bool {
    return true
}
#endif
```